# Find and close/unlink message queues in the system

Tags: ipc, message-queue, mq, mqueue

I have a SLES-11 machine on which I am not the root where I am building software code that makes extensive use of message queues. Due to some bugs, Now have an error:

`mq_open: Too many open files`

I am using the command `ipcs -a` but I do not see my message queues. So I can't use `ipcrm` command.

So, right now I cannot use the machine at all. Is there a way to find message queues (opened by me) in the system and close them ?

Info:
I do not have a `/dev/mqueue` in my system. I am also not the `root` user

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like whoever installed MQ on that server did NOT read the manual.  There is a whole section for Linux kernel parameters that needed to be checked: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zi00760_.htm